# How to prevent the drag if the user clicks the round in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have group element it has circle and rect elements. User can drag the group element, so both rect and circle element will move. It is working fine. But I need to prevent the drag if the user clicks on the circle element. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk6r7L8o/)

```js
const x = 100;
var y = 100;

var grid = d3.select("#svg-area");

var g = grid.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${x},${y})`)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function() {
      var x1 = d3.event.x - 30;
      var y1 = d3.event.y - 10;
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" +
        (x1) + "," + (y1) + ")")
    }));
newNode(g);

function newNode(g, text) {

  var textWid = 100;
  console.log('wid ', textWid);
  g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "new-nodes")
    .attr("x", '10')
    .attr("y", '0')
    .attr("rx", '6')
    .attr("ry", '6')
    .attr("width", textWid)
    .attr("height", '35')
    .style("fill", "#8c259f")
    .style("stroke", "#222")
    .style("cursor", "move");

  g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "new-nodes")
    .attr("cx", '10')
    .attr("cy", '17')
    .attr("r", '6')
    .style("fill", "#dedede")
    .style("stroke", "#b2b0b0")
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .on("click", function(d) {
      /*             d3.event.preventDefault();
                  d3.event.stopPropagation();
                   */
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg-area" class="chart-area" width="500" height="500" pointer-events="all" style="cursor: crosshair; touch-action: none;">
</svg>
```

Comment: [`drag.filter([filter])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way - the one closest to your code - is to change `on("click"` to `on("mousedown"`. A "click" event is registered when the mouse button is released again. A "mousedown" event is clearly registered before that. And the mousedown event is the one that triggers "dragstart".

```js
const x = 100;
var y = 100;

var grid = d3.select("#svg-area");

var g = grid.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${x},${y})`)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function() {
      var x1 = d3.event.x - 30;
      var y1 = d3.event.y - 10;
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" +
        (x1) + "," + (y1) + ")")
    }));
newNode(g);

function newNode(g, text) {

  var textWid = 100;
  console.log('wid ', textWid);
  g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "new-nodes")
    .attr("x", '10')
    .attr("y", '0')
    .attr("rx", '6')
    .attr("ry", '6')
    .attr("width", textWid)
    .attr("height", '35')
    .style("fill", "#8c259f")
    .style("stroke", "#222")
    .style("cursor", "move");

  g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "new-nodes")
    .attr("cx", '10')
    .attr("cy", '17')
    .attr("r", '6')
    .style("fill", "#dedede")
    .style("stroke", "#b2b0b0")
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .on("mousedown", function(d) {
      d3.event.preventDefault();
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg-area" class="chart-area" width="500" height="500" pointer-events="all" style="cursor: crosshair; touch-action: none;">
</svg>
```

---

Alternatively, you could just move the event to the rectangle and use [`d3.drag().container`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/v0.3.1/README.md#drag_container). Normally, `d3.drag` calculates the distance between the event and the parent element. Now, we need the grandparent, because the parent (the `g` element) is the thing we want to drag around.

I also changed the `g` element to use a datum object, so you can more easily move it.

```js
var grid = d3.select("#svg-area");

var g = grid.append("g")
  .datum({
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;
  });
newNode(g);

function newNode(g, text) {

  var textWid = 100;
  console.log('wid ', textWid);
  g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "new-nodes")
    .attr("x", '10')
    .attr("y", '0')
    .attr("rx", '6')
    .attr("ry", '6')
    .attr("width", textWid)
    .attr("height", '35')
    .style("fill", "#8c259f")
    .style("stroke", "#222")
    .style("cursor", "move")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .container(grid.node())
      .on("drag", function() {
        d3.select(this.parentNode)
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            d.x += d3.event.dx;
            d.y += d3.event.dy;
            return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;
          });
      }));

  g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "new-nodes")
    .attr("cx", '10')
    .attr("cy", '17')
    .attr("r", '6')
    .style("fill", "#dedede")
    .style("stroke", "#b2b0b0")
    .style("cursor", "pointer");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg-area" class="chart-area" width="500" height="500" pointer-events="all" style="cursor: crosshair; touch-action: none;">
</svg>
```