# D3js drag() returns strange results on chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, d3.js

On pc chrome it works fine, on chrome mobile emulator(or android chroem) the arrow jumps over the circle.
x and y return by `d3.pointers(event)[0]` are not linear like this for y axis =>
156, 100, 157, 101, 158, 102.

```js
drawCompass({
  radius: 120
})

function drawCompass(data) {

  const compasColor = '#ccc'
  // const { x, y } = map.latLngToLayerPoint([data.lat, data.long])
  const x = y = 190;
  const r = data.radius

  svg = d3.select("svg")
  svg
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .attr("r", r)
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("stroke", compasColor)
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("fill-opacity", .0)

  drawArrow("steelblue", 0, "0", "");

  function drawArrow(color, angle, text_inner, text_outer) {

    const outer_id = "outer_" + color + Date.now(); //id for line text 
    const inner_id = "inner"
    const arrowGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class", "arrowGroup");
    const offset = 30;

    //line radius
    arrowGroup
      .append("path")
      .attr("id", inner_id) //normall
      .attr("class", "compassLines")
      .attr("d", d3.line()([
        [x, y - r],
        [x, y],
      ]))
      .attr("stroke", compasColor)
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("fill", "none");


    // line and background for text outside the compass circle 
    const dragger = arrowGroup
      .append("path")
      .attr("id", outer_id) //normall
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 20)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
      .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("d", d3.line()([
        [x, y - r],
        [x, y - r - 30]
      ]))
      .call(
        d3.drag().on("drag", dragged)
      )

    function dragged(event) {
      const arrow_position = d3.pointers(event)[0];
      console.log('arrow_position', arrow_position);
      var angle123 = geometric.lineAngle([
        [x, y], arrow_position
      ]);
      const tempAngle = Math.ceil(angle123 + 90)
      const displayAngel = tempAngle < 0 ? 360 + tempAngle : tempAngle
      const arrow = this.parentNode;
      d3.select(arrow)
        .attr('transform', `rotate(${angle123 + 90} ${x} ${y})`);
    }
    return arrowGroup
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .compassText {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-anchor: middle;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/geometric@1.0.0/build/geometric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <svg width="380" height="380"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually dove way too deep on this one, so bear with me.

The first part of the solution is actually similar to one I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64847422/5015356). Dragging calculates the distance between the current dragged element and a container. Normally, that container is the parent node. However, if you move the parent node of the drag handle (like you do), then the container is offset against itself, which breaks. If you make the grandparent the container instead, using `this.parentNode.parentNode`, the varying output goes away.

All this actually happens within [`d3.pointer`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/a042a10ce223e6be18a077c224b6e034a1927b5f/src/pointer.js) in `d3.selection`, where the function is called with a Touch `event` and the .container `node`. The `node` being the problem here, because it is equal to the node you're trying to move.

---

Now, that being solved, everything looked good. However, on my mobile simulator, the wiggling remained, even while the output was stable. The following image is the result of `console.log(event.x, event.y, angle123)`. As you can see, the first two remain stable, but the last one wiggles.

[image]

The reason for that wiggling is that you're using `d3.pointers()`, which automatically calls `d3.pointer()` again. But this time, it uses the wrong `node`. So not the grandparent, but the parent. So instead of using `d3.pointer`, you can get the equivalent values yourself.

```
var angle123 = geometric.lineAngle([
    [x, y], [event.x, event.y]
]);
```

And that really solves the problem.

```js
drawCompass({
  radius: 120
})

function drawCompass(data) {

  const compasColor = '#ccc'
  // const { x, y } = map.latLngToLayerPoint([data.lat, data.long])
  const x = y = 190;
  const r = data.radius

  svg = d3.select("svg")
  svg
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .attr("r", r)
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("stroke", compasColor)
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("fill-opacity", .0)

  drawArrow("steelblue", 0, "0", "");

  function drawArrow(color, angle, text_inner, text_outer) {

    const outer_id = "outer_" + color + Date.now(); //id for line text 
    const inner_id = "inner"
    const arrowGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class", "arrowGroup");
    const offset = 30;

    //line radius
    arrowGroup
      .append("path")
      .attr("id", inner_id) //normall
      .attr("class", "compassLines")
      .attr("d", d3.line()([
        [x, y - r],
        [x, y],
      ]))
      .attr("stroke", compasColor)
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("fill", "none");


    // line and background for text outside the compass circle 
    const dragger = arrowGroup
      .append("path")
      .attr("id", outer_id) //normall
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 20)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
      .style("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("d", d3.line()([
        [x, y - r],
        [x, y - r - 30]
      ]))
      .call(
        d3.drag()
          .container(function() { return this.parentNode.parentNode; })
          .on("drag", dragged)
      )

    function dragged(event) {
      var angle123 = geometric.lineAngle([
        [x, y], [event.x, event.y]
      ]);
      const tempAngle = Math.ceil(angle123 + 90)
      const displayAngel = tempAngle < 0 ? 360 + tempAngle : tempAngle
      const arrow = this.parentNode;
      d3.select(arrow)
        .attr('transform', `rotate(${angle123 + 90} ${x} ${y})`);
    }
    return arrowGroup
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .compassText {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-anchor: middle;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/geometric@1.0.0/build/geometric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <svg width="380" height="380"></svg>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224788/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-serg).